# What is the math behind magnetic shielding?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have found plenty of stuff online about how a magnetic shield is composed in a way that "field lines are attracted to it and flow easily within it", thereby creating a shield in the inside (considering a tube e.g.). However I feel that just simply explains nothing about what is actually happening, it is just a failed attempt to put some non intuitive math into words. I would think that somehow the magnetic shielding material, when put in a field, generates an opposite field cancelling it out. But why does that happen only inside the tube? And how do the field lines flow within the material in a direction not parallel to the field itself? What is the math for the shielding?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just more permeable. Consider a conductor vs a dielectric - where do the electric field lines go?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning, for a static magnetic field, magnetic shielding is not done by cancelling the field. That would require diamagnetic materials (e.g. a superconductor). Instead, things like mu-metal are very good paramagnets so the common explanation is that they "short-circuit" the fields in a sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance